# Angular passing variable to other page

Tags: angular

In my angular project, let say I have following setup:

**Main Page:**

.html:

```
<div class="main component" *ngFor="let item of items;">
    <my-card [info]="item"></my-card>               
</div>
```

**Component page:**

.ts:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-card',
    templateUrl: 'myCard.html'
})

export class myCard{
  @Input() info: Array<any>;      

}
```

.html:

```
 <div class="subComponent"> {{info}}</div>
```

The idea is to use the `myCard` html template inside of the main page, which works just fine.

However somehow the `info` is undefined inside of `.ts` file.

How would I change the code so that `info` variable from the `main page` is defined?

```
 export class myCard{
  @Input() info: Array<any>;   

  console.log(info);  //Currently undefined

};
```

Comment: item is not array i think ;so this should be @Input() info:any;

Comment: Have you tried using `ngOnInit` hook?

Comment: To be clear, `console.log` statement should be inside `ngOnInit`

Comment: Why `console.log(info);` is floating outside the methods?

Comment: @steve Kim your issue resolve or not ?

Comment: Thanks guys! `ngOnInit` was what I was missing. learned something new. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { Component, Input, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-card',
    templateUrl: 'myCard.html'
})

export class myCard implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Input() info: Array<any>;

    ngOnInit() {
       console.log(this.info)
    }
    ngOnChanges(changes : SimpleChanges) {
       if(typeof changes['info'] !== 'undefined'){
         console.log(this.info)
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-card',
    templateUrl: 'myCard.html'
})

export class myCard{
  @Input() info: any;

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.info);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

please check [example code](https://plnkr.co/edit/VZ7TJRElsN6Bhu6pToGv?p=preview), if possible please share your code if it does not help.

```
import { Component }  from '@angular/core';

import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div *ngFor="let name of names">
     <app-child [name]="name"></app-child>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'hello';

  names:string[]=[];

  constructor(){

    this.names=['raj','honey','kinshuk'];

  }

}

import {Component,Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.template.html'
})
export class ChildComponent{

  @Input() name;

}
```